# AS3 pass var from main class to another class

Tags: actionscript-3

My code works but its not getting the VAR in the last function. What am I missing?

Main Class Code

```
package {

    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.*;

    import com.Bubble;


    public class numberPop extends MovieClip 
    {

        public var numberBubble:Bubble;

        public function numberPop() 
        {

            addBubble(3);

        }


        public function addBubble(num:Number)
        {
            var i:Number = num;         
            numberBubble = new Bubble(i);
            addChild(numberBubble);
        }

    }

}
```

Second Class Code: Bubbles.as

```
package com {

    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.*;


    public class Bubble extends MovieClip 
    {

        public var num:Number;

        public function Bubble(num:Number) 
        {
            super();
            num = num;
            trace("Number is: " + num); /// WORKS !!!!!

            this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, bubbleAction);



        }

        public function bubbleAction(e:Event)
        {
            trace(num); // DOES NOT WORK BUT SHOULD. 
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: I would try renaming `public function Bubble(num:Number) ` to some other variable name. It could be conflicting with `public var num:Number;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your argument in constructor is overriding class property. Change:

```
num = num;
```

to

```
this.num = num;
```